# Hosting Environment initiated shutdown

Tags: packages

I am getting log warnings as below when trying to install one package on fresh Sitecore 9.0.2 instance. I don't understand why its getting restarted again.

Is there any app pool setting which causes such behavior?

> WARN  Shutdown message: Change Notification for critical directories.
>   
> bin dir change or directory rename
>   Hosting Environment initiated shutdown

Comment: What is in the package?

Comment: If your package contains dlls for the bin folder, this is a normal behaviour

Comment: its ucommerce package, which adds few dll's.

Comment: but its causes app restart, new log file is created and then after there is no msg or error related to package in new log file

Comment: Is there any specific app pool setting which causes it to recycle frequently , because in sitecore upgrade process also we are performing same operation, but at that time i never see such errors.

Comment: What is the app pool identity of your application in IIS?

Comment: the app pool identiry of application is "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

Comment: hmmm... I am not sure about this but could you please try by changing it to Network Service?

Answer (score 4):

In your comment, you say:

> its ucommerce package, which adds few dll's.

The package is updating DLLs which are being placed in the `bin` directory. When you update DLLs, Sitecore needs to restart in order to load those DLLs. This is normal behavior. The log message you see is Sitecore telling you that it is restarting due to a change in DLLs in the `bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

That’s normal. Sitecore would restart with a warning message if you are changing(adding/editing) any files in bin directory. Your package contains dlls which are being added to bin